# Finding a current in a given circuit

Tags: voltage, current, parallel, series, kirchhoffs-laws

The problem has given the following circuit:

[image]

And asked to find the value(s) of Ix if the elements absorb the power(s) given.

I tired to set up KCL/KVL but I keep getting stuck.

I first drew this:
[image]

And set KVL1 = (Ra)(i1)-(Rb)(i2)
        KVL2 = (Rb)(i2)+(Rc)(i3)

After that I am confused on how to continue without knowing the resistances.

Comment: Your KVL's are missing Vo and R1 and I would think you should write a KVL equation something like \$ \text{ KVL1: } V_r + V_s + i \cdot R_t = 0 \$. KVL1 self has no value.

Comment: Try to represent those boxes (which I assume are passive components) as Thevenin equivalents, a resistor in series with a voltage supply.

Comment: This block diagram suggests you have2 sources 48V and B, 8W with 2 loads A+C= 88W thus the 48 V supply delivers 80W so Ix is simply 80W/48V = answer

Comment: B might not be an ideal source, and have some internal resistance. The two loads, A,C, could be more than just a resistive load. You should also include the power losses on the resistor R1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the fact that the power in a closed system is conserved. That is,
the sum,
$$\sum_i P_i = 0$$
Where,
$$ 0=P_{V_0}+P_{R_1}+P_A+P_B+P_C.$$
So,
$$ 0=-I_XV_0+R_1I_X^2+48-8+40.$$
Hence,
$$ 0=-48I_X+4I_X^2+80.$$
This will give you two possible values for \$I_X\$. Maybe both results are ok, or there is a way to further determine which of the \$I_X\$ is the right one. If someone wants to further deduce it, please go-ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Redrawing things can sometimes help a little. Here's how I might attempt to redraw your schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFDc7W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you have 5 equations and 5 unknowns. (Substitution could reduce that, if you like.) A quick check suggests that you will find two equally valid answers for the problem, though. You should also find (in both cases) that \$I_\text{B}\$ is negative (goes opposite to the indicated arrow.)